# How to access variable from another class directly(i.e. without using class name or object)?

Tags: java

Suppose, I've a class `TestA` which has variable `int Age` like -

```
class TestA{
  int Age = 25;
}
```

and I want to access it from class `TestB` without using class name(in this case, I'll have to declare `Age` as `static`) and without creating object of `TestA`

How can we achieve this in Java?

**Note:** `TestB` is not subclass of `TestA`

Comment: If `TestB` subclasses `TestA` and the `age` field is protected or public, then you can refer to `age` directly in `TestB`.

Comment: No, `TestB` is not subclass of `TestA`. Let me update question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: The question makes no sense. Without an instance of `TestA`, the field doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define that field as static and do something like:

```
 import static TestA.Age;

 class TestB {
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(Age);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot SMA!!! This is what I was looking for. I had read this somewhere very long ago, but couldn't remember. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to do this for many variables in TestA without importing each one individually?

Comment: Use `import static TestA.*; and then System.out.println(Age + " " + Name);`